# Step through a list in Beamer at a sub-item level

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am trying to show a list piece by piece.
I know that you can use `\begin{itemize}[<+->]`
to make items appear one-by-one.
However, how do you control smaller parts of each item,
to make them appear one-by-one?

In the minimum working example below,
you can see that the items slowly jump upwards
from overlays 1 to 4.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\begin{itemize}
\item
Question for overlay 1? \\
\only<2->{Answer for overlay 2}
\item<3->
Question for overlay 3? \\
\only<4->{Answer for overlay 4}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the following suit your purpose?

*(The way I understood your question, subitems should also appear in order after the main items.
So, items 1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 2.1, 2.2 should appear in this order.
If it is otherwise, please let me know.)*

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item <1-> Question for overlay 1?
    \begin{itemize}
    \item <2-> Answer for overlay 2
    \item <3-> More answer
    \end{itemize}
  \item <4-> Question for overlay 3?
    \begin{itemize}
    \item <5-> Answer for overlay 2
    \item <6-> Still more answer
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```